# dynamic populate a select input from mysql

Tags: php, joomla

Hi I am trying to populate an entire Drop down list with MySQL but I cant get it to work, can you please help?

My code:

```
$database=& JFactory::getDBO();

$database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,training,trainingDate FROM training ');

$result = $database->loadObjectList();

 echo '<select name="whatever">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo '<option value="$row[training_id" />';
    }

echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Try echo '<option value=$row[training_id] />'; instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your echo string doesn't allow for embedded variables because you are using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Implement this echo instead:

```
echo '<option value="' . $row["training_id"] . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing what the output is, it's hard to know whether this is the only issue, but the glaring error in your code is this:

```
echo '<option value="$row[training_id" />';
```

Because this is in single quotes, the variable is not interpreted. You need to use double quotes (and close the square brackets!):

```
echo "<option value=\"{$row['training_id']}\" />";
```

Note that I have changed the style of variable interpretation to use curly brackets: I believe this is easier to read and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using single quotes, you are also:

1. Missing a closing square bracket.
2. Missing the closing tag for the `<option>`.

You probably want to change your output to something like this, so you display some option text to the user:

```
echo '<select name="whatever">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['training_id'] . '"> ' . $row['training'] . '</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$database= &JFactory::getDBO();
$database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,training,trainingDate FROM training');
$result = $database->loadObjectList();

echo '<select name="whatever">';
foreach ($result as $row) {
   echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'" />';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Use #__ for table prefix.

Comment: The select query works fine, is just that I cannot populate the select box with the ids...

Answer (score 1):

```
$database= &JFactory::getDBO();
$database->setQuery('SELECT training_id,training,trainingDate FROM training');
$result = $database->loadObjectList();

echo '<select name="whatever">';
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row->training_id.'" />';
}
echo '</select>';
```

This code works, but populates the list with empty options. I had to put a simple echo in as shown below, and works just fine. For some reason, $row->teremnev is empty for me. Im sure this is not the right way, but it works.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT teremnev FROM #__teremlista";
$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResultArray(); 
echo '<select name="termek">' ;
foreach ($result as $row) {
echo '<option value="'.$row->teremnev.'" />';
echo $row;
}
echo '</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<option>Select Training</option>

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
 echo "<option>". $row['training_name']."</option>";

}
</select>
```